# How to remove banners from matlab generated videos?

Tags: matlab

I am running matlab in my HPC server from terminal. My program generates video output. The program runs fine, but produces output with a banner like below:
[image]

How to avoid this banner?

Updating with a minimal reproducible script etc:
My slurm script in HPC:

```
#!/bin/sh
### sbatch config parameters must start with #SBATCH and must precede any other command. to ignore just add another # - like ##SBATCH
#SBATCH --partition main                        ### specify partition name where to run a job. Any node: ‘main’; NVidia 2080: ‘rtx2080’; 1080: ‘gtx1080’
#SBATCH --time 0-10:30:00                      ### limit the time of job running. Make sure it is not greater than the partition time limit (7 days)!! Format: D-H:MM:SS
#SBATCH --job-name my_job                   ### name of the job. replace my_job with your desired job name
#SBATCH --output my_job-id-%J.out                ### output log for running job - %J is the job number variable
#SBATCH --mail-user=xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com      ### user’s email for sending job status notifications
#SBATCH --mail-type=BEGIN,END,FAIL             ### conditions for sending the email. ALL,BEGIN,END,FAIL, REQUEU, NONE
#SBATCH --gres=gpu:1                ### number of GPUs (can't exceed 8 gpus for now) allocating more than 1 requires the IT team permission

### Print some data to output file ###
echo "SLURM_JOBID"=$SLURM_JOBID
echo "SLURM_JOB_NODELIST"=$SLURM_JOB_NODELIST



matlab -nodisplay -nosplash -nodesktop -r "run('./mat2video.m');exit;"
```

My matlab script in HPC:

```
data=rand(100,768,1024);
x=size(data);

v = VideoWriter('video.avi');
open(v);
for i=1:x(1)
   d=reshape(data(i,:,:),[x(2) x(3)]);
   imshow(d);
   frame = getframe(gcf);
   writeVideo(v,frame);
end

close(v);
```

I submit the job via slurm `sbatch` command. The version of matlab is 2021A.

Comment: I’m pretty sure that banner appears only once, if you manually dismiss it, it will not show up again.

Comment: Please read [mre]: How are you generating the video? I have never seen this banner in exported figures.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: It comes each time. I will edit my question with the scripts. I cannot manually edit it since I am working from a command prompt by submitting matlab job via slurm in HPC

Comment: manually cancel the banner*

Comment: You don’t need to use a figure to save an array as a video. And you don’t even need to loop. `writeVideo(v,data)` does the job. You just need to reorder dimensions (`permute`) so that `data` is 4D and ordered (height,width,1,frames).

Comment: That said, I’m surprised that `getFrame` grabs that UI banner as well, it sounds like a bug to me. I think you should report that to MathWorks.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: Thank you very much. Let me know the link where I should report it?

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/support/servicerequests/reportabug.html